# Call to undefined functions not working on my server

Tags: php

I'm working with someone else's code and I'm noticing that there are functions which are being used that don't exist in `PHP` and are not defined anywhere as `custom functions`. **Essentially, these functions are just not anywhere to be seen and i cannot locate on google.**

Here are a list:

- imagesharpen
- imagebrightnesscontrast

Has anyone ever seen or heard of these functions? Is it possible that the developer somehow created and installed these functions into the php compiled binary?

Not quite sure what to do here.

Here's the php configure command:

'./configure' '--with-apxs2=/srv/apache/bin/apxs' '--with-mysql=/srv/mysql' '--with-mysqli=/srv/mysql/bin/mysql_config' '--with-xsl' '--enable-sockets' '--with-pcre-dir=/usr/local' '--with-gd=/usr/local' '--with-jpeg-dir=/usr/local' '--with-png-dir=/usr/local' '--with-freetype-dir=/usr/local/include/freetype2' '--with-gettext' '--with-config-file-path=/srv/apache/conf' '--enable-bcmath=shared' '--with-curl' '--enable-soap' '--with-openssl=/usr/local/ssl' '--with-openssl-dir=/usr/local/ssl'

Answer (score 1):

It *is* most likely a custom defined function, Why not ask PHP to search it for you?

```
$rf = new ReflectionFunction('imagesharpen');
echo $rf->getFileName() . ':' . $rf->getStartLine();
```

If its errors the function does not exist perhaps try loading it in later in run-time. If it shows empty values you're indeed dealing with an internal function.

What modules are installed? Please run `phpinfo()` as it might give more insight.

Comment: Weird. It's returning blank but clearly its there or else it would fail. I think it might be a function that the developer must have compiled himself? Can I view this code somehow? I put the configure command in the question

Answer (score 0):

This was from a custom php module.

Comment: please delete your question in that case so it doesn't end up polluting web searches in the future for other people =) Or, update the post to be far more specific about what frameworks etc. are being used and then write an answer explaining where those functions are found.